# Move element shortdesc

Tags: xslt

How to position the element shortdesc after element h1 by using xslt transformation.
Currently I get the content of each element by the following code.

```
<xsl:template match="shortdesc" mode="body">       
   <shortdesc>
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="body"/>
   </shortdesc>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="p" mode="body">       
   <p>
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="body"/>
   </p>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="h1" mode="body">      
   <h1>
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="body"/>
   </h1>
</xsl:template>
```

Source File

```
<topic>    
   <h1>text</h1>
   <p>text</p>
   <p>text</p>
   <shortdesc>text</shortdesc>
   <p>text</p>
   <p>text</p>
</topic>
```

Target File (It should look like this after transformation)

```
<topic>
   <h1>text</h1>
   <shortdesc>text</shortdesc>
   <p>text</p>
   <p>text</p>
   <p>text</p>
   <p>text</p>
</topic>
```

Thank you for your ideas

Comment: Your source file must have a root element which for some reason you're not showing us. You can achieve the desired order by adding a template matching the root element and from there applying templates to the child nodes in the order you want them.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot he root element. I have added the element topic

Comment: And where is the template matching `topic`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the trick using:

```
<xsl:template match="h1" mode="body">      
   <h1>
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="body"/>
   </h1>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="../shortdesc" mode="desc"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="shortdesc" mode="body"/>
<xsl:template match="shortdesc" mode="desc">       
   <shortdesc>
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="body"/>
   </shortdesc>
</xsl:template>
```

and btw, don't you want to replace you templates with something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="*" mode="body">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="body"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

?

Comment: Too complicated. Both of them.

Comment: I don't think using explicit apply-template it is a very complicated trick :)

Answer (score 0):

To simplify the example to the problem at hand, given the following input:

**XML**

```
<topic>    
   <h1>text</h1>
   <p>text</p>
   <p>text</p>
   <shortdesc>text</shortdesc>
   <p>text</p>
   <p>text</p>
</topic>
```

the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/topic">       
   <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="h1"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="shortdesc"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="p"/>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="h1 | shortdesc | p">      
   <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will return:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<topic>
  <h1>text</h1>
  <shortdesc>text</shortdesc>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
</topic>
```